# (Swift) Stripe Apple Pay Payment not completed

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, stripe-payments

Trying to setup Stripe apple pay in my project, but keep running into "payment not completed" as seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMIx6.png

Error seems to be occurring due to processing not finishing and timing out. I have been unable to get the block to complete and display any error.

**Where I'm calling the payment model**

```
if backendModel.paymentIntentParams != nil {
    PaymentButton() {
        applePayModel.pay(amount: cartCost, total: totalCost, clientSecret: backendModel.paymentIntentParams?.clientSecret, pi: backendModel.paymentIntentParams?.stripeId)
    }
    .cornerRadius(25)
    .padding([.horizontal, .bottom])
}
```

**Apple Pay Model**

```
    func pay(amount: Double, total: Double, clientSecret: String?, pi: String?) {
        self.clientSecret = clientSecret
        self.pi = pi
        
        // Configure our Apple Pay payment request
        let paymentRequest = StripeAPI.paymentRequest(withMerchantIdentifier: "merchant.com.myapp", country: "US", currency: "usd")
        
        paymentRequest.requiredBillingContactFields = [.postalAddress]
        paymentRequest.requiredShippingContactFields = []
        
        paymentRequest.paymentSummaryItems = [
            PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Subtotal", amount: NSDecimalNumber(value: amount)),
            PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Delivery Fee + Taxes", amount: NSDecimalNumber(value: 5.00)),
            PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Total", amount: NSDecimalNumber(value: total))
        ]
        
        // Present apple pay context
        let applePayContext = STPApplePayContext(paymentRequest: paymentRequest, delegate: self)
        applePayContext?.presentApplePay()
    }
    
    
    func applePayContext(_ context: STPApplePayContext, didCreatePaymentMethod paymentMethod: STPPaymentMethod, paymentInformation: PKPayment, completion: @escaping STPIntentClientSecretCompletionBlock) {
        // payment method was created -> confirm PaymentIntent
        if (self.clientSecret != nil) {
            // call the completion block with the client secret
            completion(clientSecret, nil)
        } else {
            completion(nil, NSError())
        }
    }
    
    func applePayContext(_ context: STPApplePayContext, didCompleteWith status: STPPaymentStatus, error: Error?) {
        // get the payment status or error
        self.paymentStatus = status
        self.lastPaymentError = error
        
        if status == .success {
            print("Payment success!")
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**
Video of the error I'm getting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCeOR.gif

Comment: [The `STPIntentClientSecretCompletionBlock` passes an `error`](https://stripe.dev/stripe-ios/docs/Typealiases.html#/s:14StripeApplePay36STPIntentClientSecretCompletionBlocka) which you seem to be ignoring.  Can you add code to surface the details of that `error` and see if that points you in the right direction, or update your question with those `error` details?

Comment: Could you explain how to surface the details of the error? @Justin Michael

Comment: Sorry, my last message wasn't very clear.  What I meant is that you're calling `completion` and passing an `NSError()` which won't tell you anything useful. I think something is likely amiss with the content of `paymentIntentParams`, but there's no way to know given this code.  Can you add more logging in general to figure out exactly where the code gets stuck and to make sure the variables (like `paymentIntentParams`) contain what you expect, then update your question with those details?

Comment: No worries, I'm unfamiliar with swift and stripe. I dug deeper into the problem and found that I am recovering the correct client secret and publishable key. I did notice that the applePayContext is never firing so the completion is never called. I think the payment not completed is the result of a timeout @JustinMichael

Comment: Meaning `didCreatePaymentMethod` is not firing?  You call `applePayContext?.presentApplePay()` and then the Apple Pay sheet appears... and then what?  Does it immediately go to "Payment not complete" or does it do that after you authenticate with Touch/Face ID?  Or does something else happen?

Comment: The Apple Pay sheet appears and the user can enter their payment and billing. It’s after the user continues on to processing the payment that it is failing @JustinMichael

Comment: Can you confirm the behavior of `didCreatePaymentMethod`?  Is it running or does it never get called?

Comment: It is never being called @JustinMichael

Comment: And there are no other errors surfaced anywhere?  Can you confirm you followed all the steps and setup in [Stripe's guide for Apple Pay](https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay?platform=ios#accept), including registering your merchant ID, creating an Apple Pay certificate, and integrating all of that with Xcode?

Comment: I have no other errors surfaced and have gone through the steps for setup a few times. I'll attach a video to show the error better @JustinMichael

Comment: I'm not sure what else to suggest.  If neither of [the Apple Pay delegate methods](https://stripe.dev/stripe-ios/docs/Protocols/STPApplePayContextDelegate.html) are being called and there are no errors showing up anywhere it's a bit of a mystery.  Your code is setting the delegate to `self`... is `self` somehow getting destroyed or discarded before the delegate methods can be called?  Can you maybe try other iOS devices to see if the same thing happens?